# Using sudo command in a child process using node

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, child-process

I am trying to copy a bundle directory into a root directory of a remote server. I try to do this using node and so far I achieved piping the tar content to server and untar it. However when I try to move the directory to root folder it requires `sudo` access and I just couldn't find a way to do it. I tried `-t` option for pseudoterminal but I guess that works running from a shell. Here is what I have done so far, any help is highly appreciated:

```
const path = require("path");
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../");
const allCommands = [];
/*
 *
 *
 * 1-) cd to the root folder of the app
 * 2-) tar dist folder and pipe the result to the ssh connection
 * 3-) connect to server with ssh
 * 4-) try to create dist and old_dists folder, if not existing they will be created otherwise they will give an error and rest of the script will continue running
 * 5-) cp contents of dist folder to old_dists/dist_$(dateofmoment) folder so if something is wrong somehow you have an backup of the existing config
 * 6-) untar the piped tar content into dist folder, untar only files under the first parent directory --strip-components=1 flag, if it was 2 it will dive 2 level from the root folder
 *
 *
 */
allCommands.push("cd " + absolutePath);
allCommands.push("tar -czvP dist | ssh  hostnameofmyserver 'mkdir dist ; mkdir old_dists; cp -R dist/ old_dists/dist_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S) && tar -xzvP -C dist --strip-components=1'");
//I would like to untar the incoming file into /etc/myapp for example rather than my home directory, this requires sudo and don't know how to handle it
exec(allCommands.join(" && "),
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
  });
```

Also whats the best place for storing web application folder in ubuntu server where multiple user can deploy an app, is it a good practice to make the owner of the directory `root` user, or it just doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [man page for ssh](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh), you can specify multiple `-t` arguments to force pty allocation even if the OpenSSH client's stdin is not a tty (which it won't be by default when you spawn a child process in node).

From there you should be able to simply write the password to the child process's `.stdin` stream when you see the sudo prompt on the `.stdout` stream.

On a semi-related note, if you want more (programmatic) control over the ssh connection or you don't want to spin up a child process, there is the [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module. You could even do the tarring within node too if you wanted, as there are also tar modules on npm.

Comment: Ok I thing this is better, but after entering the password nothing happens: `process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  child.stdin.write(String(chunk) + "\r\n");
})`

Comment: For one thing, you shouldn't assume that each `chunk` will be a complete line. Also, if you're reading from `process.stdin` and it's a tty, it may already include a line ending in the stream anyway. Did you try just directly writing to `child.stdin` once you see the sudo prompt?

Comment: I used process accidentally, when I use child.stdin.write("password") nothing happens. `stderr` prints `~^Z [suspend ssh]` when the password is prompted. Actually I want to have a script for automating a deploy to server. And this script can be used by multiple user, therefore this approach seems wrong to me,do you have any idea whats a better approach for such a requirement